# <supports-gl-texture> Attributes

Tags: android, opengl-es

Hi Stackoverflow users.

I am currently building a android game which is pretty art heavy.
I want to build multiple apks with different texture compressions so my app has a lot of device support.

I currently want to use the ETC2 texture compression and the PVRTC texture compression.

I checked the android developer documentation and I found this list.
I do not see ETC2 in this one, does it exist or do I need to use another texture compression?

supports-gl-texture Attributes.

```
 1. GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture
 2. GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture
 3. GL_AMD_compressed_3DC_texture
 4. GL_AMD_compressed_ATC_texture
 5. GL_EXT_texture_compression_latc
 6. GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1
 7. GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc
 8. GL_IMG_texture_compression_pvrtc
```

Notes:

Unity Build.

Texture Compressions: PVRCT, ETC2.

Android

Answer (score 1):

Sorry this was a stupid question.

For anyone searching for this.

> GL_OES_compressed_ETC2_RGB8_texture

Comment: Is this officially supported by Google? I'd like to use it in my app, but the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-gl-texture-element) does not still specify `GL_OES_compressed_ETC2_RGB8_texture`. Currently our workaround is to check if `supportedGlVersion` is `0x00030000` because all Android devices supporting OpenGL ES 3 support ETC2.